# How to get all confirmed sold transactions by using Metaplex Solana?

Tags: blockchain, solana, solana-web3js, metaplex

I'm wondering if anyone here knows to use Metaplex to get all confirmed sold transactions by using mint address? SolScan.io has a sample endpoint

`https://api.solscan.io/nft/trade?mint=Cipp5qJe9XGcZ4bMcSYC5RdoewmEjpkLo12RytkyDsQC&offset=0&limit=20`. Can we do something like this using Metaplex Solana?

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to find all sale transactions for a given mint from chain. My answer will be using node package @solana/web3.js

To achieve this you have to

1. get all transaction signatures of the mint with [getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2)
2. get the parsed transaction content with [getParsedTransactions](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransactions).
3. Check the programs that are involved in the tx. e.g. MEisE1HzehtrDpAAT8PnLHjpSSkRYakotTuJRPjTpo8 is Magic eden V1.
4. Verify if it was a sale. How this can be done depends on the marketplace program. One idea could be to check if there was sol transferred to the creators.